# Grails 3.3: transient properties and GrailsDomainClassProperty

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

Contemplating upgrade of a plugin from Grails 3.2.11 to Grails 3.3.2 while accomodating the slashing change in the domain class API. PersistentProperty replaces GrailsDomainClassProperty but has no isPersistent() method.

How do I find out programmatically if a domain class property is transient? Does PersistentEntity return transient properties at all?

(I tend to use transient properties a lot. Great for productivity.)

Answer (score 0):

`PersistentEntity.getPersistentProperties()` will give you list of properties to be persisted - meaning it doesn't include transient properties. You can try:

```
GrailsClassUtils.getStaticPropertyValue(MyDomain, "transients")?.contains("myPropertyName")
```

Comment: Yes and no... Any getter method makes a transient property, no need to include it in 'transients'. If included, sure, your suggestion works.

Comment: "Any getter method makes a transient property" - That is not true.